# Javascript runs in template html file but not extended html file in Django application

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am writing a website in Django and Vanilla JS

I have 2 html pages, I want them both to share css but I want them to use different javascript.
Both pages extend a layout.html.

The layout.html looks begins like this

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}Social Network{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'network/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
```

My index.html (which extends my layout.html) begins like this

```
{% extends "network/layout.html" %}

{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'network/messages.js' %}"></script>
```

and my Javascript file looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    console.log("page loaded!")

    document.addEventListener('click', event => {
        const element = event.target;
        console.log("Something was clicked")
  })
});
```

It simply prints out a line when the page is loaded and when something is clicked.

However, when I go to index.html with the code like this, the javascript file is not loaded, nothing is printed out when the page is loaded or when anything is clicked.

However, if I modify the layout.html page to be like this:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}Social Network{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'network/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="{% static 'network/messages.js' %}"></script> 
    </head>
```

where I load the messages.js, and then remove it from the index.html like this:

```
{% extends "network/layout.html" %}
```

Then the javascript works, and the page loads it properly.
The only problem with this is that it also loads it for my other pages which I do not want, I only want to load message.js for index.html and I am not sure why it refuses to load when I only include it in index.html.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you extend templates. Django templates use a [block system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/). So the `script` in the index.html isn't rendered at all. You must have an empty block in `layout.html`, and override that block in `index.html`.

`layout.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}Social Network{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'network/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
    </body>
</html>
```

`index.html`

```html
{% extends "network/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<script src="{% static 'network/messages.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock content %}
```

Try adding HTML to your current `index.html`. It won't be displayed. You must enclose everything in `block`s for it to work.

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately, The javascript is still not loading in my index.html page